# Why is the absolute value of $e^{\Large{\frac{\pi i}{3}}}=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ equal to $1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Hello i have some algebra problems.
I have the following equation:

$\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=e^{\Large{\frac{\pi i}{3}}}$

but why is this? and why is the absolute value of this equation equal to $1$?

Comment: By Euler's Theorem,$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ for all real numbers $x$

Comment: The modulus (sometimes called as absolute) of a complex number $a+bi$ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Euler's formula also holds for non-real $x$, which gives the complex form of our trig functions.

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Euler's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula), we have that $ e^{x+iy} = e^x(cos(y)+isin(y))$

So in this case, $ e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}} = cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) + isin(\frac{\pi}{3})$.

Since $cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $sin(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we see that $ e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$ then equals $ \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

The absolute value of a complex number $ x+iy$ is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, so here the absolute value is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4}} = 1 $

Answer (score 1):

If we define $e^x$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$, then

$$e^{ix}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{ix}n\right)^n$$

> And while the following image is not rigorous, it does give a good conceptual understanding of why $|e^{ix}|=1$.  It also follows that $e^{ix}$ has an angle of $x$ (in radians), and with a bit of trig you could probably conclude that

$$e^{\large\frac{\pi i}3}=\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

(Which should be your $30,60,90$ triangle)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can use:

$$\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)i=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}\times e^{\arg\left(\text{z}\right)i}\tag1$$

So:

- $$\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+3}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{4}{4}}=1\tag2$$
- $$\arg\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}\right)=\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}\tag3$$

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comments, the following is known as the Euler's Theorem 
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x $$
for all real numbers $x$.

In your question, $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Plugging in, we get

$$e^{i\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}}=\cos\frac{\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
Lastly, the absolute value of $\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is given by
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}}=1.$$